# How to interpret the divergence and low effective samples warnings?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, mcmc

I am running a tutorial that teaches some novice how to use PyMC3 to conduct regression. I used the Ted talk data as example and try to find out how the number of comments, number of languages transcribed and the length of talk video predict the popularity of Ted talks. I ran the following code for PyMC3:

```
    intercept = pm.Normal("Intercept", 5, sigma=3)
    beta_duration = pm.Normal('duration', mu = 0.05, sd = 0.3) 
    beta_languages = pm.Normal('languages', mu = 0.05, sd = 0.1) 
    beta_comments = pm.Normal('comments', mu = 0.05, sd = 0.1)
    epsilon = pm.HalfCauchy('epsilon', 5)

    likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu = intercept + beta_duration * ted_talk['duration'] + beta_languages * ted_talk['languages'] + beta_comments * ted_talk['comments'], sd = epsilon, observed = ted_talk['views'])
    trace = pm.sample(4000, tune = 2000, chains = 3)
```

Result:

```
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using jitter+adapt_diag...
Sequential sampling (3 chains in 1 job)
NUTS: [epsilon, comments, languages, duration, Intercept]

Sampling 3 chains for 2_000 tune and 4_000 draw iterations (6_000 + 12_000 draws total) took 91 seconds.
There were 973 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
The acceptance probability does not match the target. It is 0.5480812333460533, but should be close to 0.8. Try to increase the number of tuning steps.
There were 973 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
There were 973 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
The number of effective samples is smaller than 10% for some parameters.
```

Question 1: What are possible reasons why the MCMC simulation returns some divergences even after tuning? As the program recommends me to increase `target_accept`, and increase tuning, which one do you think more useful? But if it highly depends, I want to know why is it?

Question 2: What are the potential problems if the effective samples are too small? Since I haven't seen any "threshold" to determine if the number of effective samples is too large/ too small (including [mcmc_diagnostic](https://jrnold.github.io/bayesian_notes/mcmc-diagnostics.html)), how much effective samples do you think in a Bayesian regression model would be reasonable?

Thank you so much for your time! Your help is tremendous!

Comment: What is "*the Ted talk data*"? Have you preprocessed it to be standardized?

Comment: It's the Ted talk data available in Kaggle that features 2550 Ted talks from 2006 to 2017. Here is a pretty good data description: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/337284_d19c9e639b22451aa3193396831d8a99.html. Of course I preprocessed and converted Unix timestamps into date time.

Comment: I'm curious the reasons why divergences after tuning will happen! And in what situation would the acceptance probability fall below some threshold such as 0.8?

Comment: I'd suggest reading/watching [Michael Betancourt](https://betanalpha.github.io/writing/), who has spent the last several years developing intuitive explanations of how HMC/NUTS works.

Comment: Thank you for your reading recommendation :)

Comment: [This tutorial / blog post](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/divergences_and_bias.html) (also by Betancourt) addresses some of the issues in the question.